# Sphinx custom makefile gives error: "Builder name link not registered or available through entry point"

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx

I'm following a (kind of) Sphinx tutorial.
They teached me how to keep links in a folder, using a `file.py` for each link, and use them with `` :xref:`link name` ``  (something like [this](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/extlinks.html)). No problem until here but now they want to costumize `makefile` to add a comand for create the link files [like you can read here for contest](https://sublime-and-sphinx-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/references.html#add-link-make-command).

The tutorial gives some code to add to `Makefile` that should create in the `links` folder a `file.py` like this:

```
# file.py
import links.link

link_name = "Sphinx External Links"
user_text = "External Links Extension"
url = "http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/ext/extlinks.html"

links.link.xref_links.update({link_name: (user_text, url)})
```

I did the canges but when use the command

```
>>> make link
```

it gives this error:

```
Running Sphinx v5.0.2

Sphinx error:
Builder name link not registered or available through entry point
```

Where I'm wrong?

I see in their [Repository](https://github.com/MarkHoeber/sublime_sphinx_guide/blob/master/Makefile) the Makefile is different from mine, I think because they use the old version (sphinx made [some changes](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/tree/af62fa61e6cbd88d0798963211e73e5ba0d55e6d/sphinx/templates/quickstart)). Here is my `Makefile` with the new code:

```
# Minimal makefile for Sphinx documentation
#

# You can set these variables from the command line, and also
# from the environment for the first two.
SPHINXOPTS    ?=
SPHINXBUILD   ?= sphinx-build
SOURCEDIR     = .
BUILDDIR      = _build
LINKSDIR      = links

# Put it first so that "make" without argument is like "make help".
help:
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M help "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)

.PHONY: help Makefile

# new code:

.PHONY: link
link:
        read -p "Enter a Unique Link Name: " link_name; \
        read -p "Enter the link text the user sees: " link_text; \
        read -p "Enter the URL: " link_url; \
        read -p "Enter the .py file name (use_lower_case_and_underscore of link name): " file_name; \
        echo "The link name is: " $$link_name; \
        echo "The link text is: " $$link_text; \
        echo "The URL is: " $$link_url; \
        echo "Creating the file: " $(LINKSDIR)/$$file_name".py"; \
        echo "Enter the link in content as :xref:\`"$$link_name"\`"; \
        echo "The user will see:" $$link_text; \
        echo "Make sure you build and test the link."; \
  echo "import links.link\n\nen_us_user_text = \"$$link_text\" \n\n\
links.xref_links.update({\"$$link_name\": (en_us_user_text, \"$$link_url\")})" \
  > $(LINKSDIR)/$$file_name".py" \

# end of new code

# Catch-all target: route all unknown targets to Sphinx using the new
# "make mode" option.  $(O) is meant as a shortcut for $(SPHINXOPTS).
%: Makefile
    @$(SPHINXBUILD) -M $@ "$(SOURCEDIR)" "$(BUILDDIR)" $(SPHINXOPTS) $(O)
```

Respect the code they had given I think I have to change the variable `LINKSDIR` because we have a different directory tree (but I tried even `LINKSDIR = docs/links`). They have:

```
Makefile
source ---|
          |--- conf.py
          |--- exts 
          |--- links ---|
                        |--- link.py 
                        |--- my_link.py
```

I have:

```
docs ---|
        |--- Makefile
        |--- conf.py
        |--- exts
        |--- links ---|
                      |--- link.py
                      |--- my_link.py
```

Maybe I have some problem in my path, for example in the link files they use:

```
import link
```

Instead in `my_link.py` I have to use:

```
import links.link
```

this look strange to me because I'm importing a module from the same directory but anyways like this that part works.

I tried even some changes in `make.bat` without results and nowhere they speak of that, so I rolled back.

Edit: I use Windows

Thank you

Comment: `%: Makefile` you need to put your new make target above this

Comment: @Iguananaut I tried to put new code between ``.PHONY: help Makefile`` and ``%: Makefile`` but doesn't change nothing

Comment: First rule of makefiles: _never_ prefix your recipes with `@` until after your entire makefile is working properly (maybe not even then).  All this does is hide the commands make is running so you can't see them.  It's like trying to debug after you set your terminal to have black text on a black background.  First rule of StackOverflow: show the complete output of the problem or at least the lines before the error, not just the error, so people can see what commands caused the error.

Comment: @MadScientist ok, I deleted the ``@`` on my new code, I tried to delete even the two ``@`` who were on the original file (the one made by sphinx), but nothing changed. I added some more output but it was (almost) all already there. Before that I activate my environment ``conda activate ./env``.